# How to remove comment count column in Posts inside the admin dashboard?

Tags: functions, wp-admin

I know how to remove from pages:

```
function remove_pages_count_columns($defaults) {
  unset($defaults['comments']);
  return $defaults;
}
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'remove_pages_count_columns');
```

But can't find the answer how to remove for posts.

I have tried:

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'remove_posts_count_columns');
```

and

```
add_filter('manage_post_columns', 'remove_post_count_columns');
```

But none of the above worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be work, if you use the filter `manage_posts_columns`.
The hook is fine, see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L714

Documentation include examples - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_posts_columns/

Example:

```
function remove_posts_columns( $columns, 'post' ) {

    unset( $columns['comments'] );
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns',  'remove_posts_columns', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Hey bueltge, thanks for your effort, but I'm getting an error trying to save this code inside the functions.php:
  `Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 101 of file wp-content/themes/simplest/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected ''post'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)`

Comment: I have removed `, 'post'` from your code and it worked! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have also the additional parameters on `add_filter` to trigger that the function have two parameters? It is necessary to inform the hook.

Comment: second prameter should be $post, a var, not a string

Comment: But in this case it is the post-type, a static value, a string 'post', and not a var that accepts different strings.